# Separating Ground and Neutrals in Mainpanel before installing sub panel

Tags: grounding, subpanel, neutral

I'm planning to get a 100 amp sub panel installed in my garage but got conflicting opinions on a point from different master electricians. The point is one electrician is saying it's a must to separate ground and neutrals in the main panel before the sub panel is installed while the other says that's not needed. I know that ground and neutrals have to be separated in the sub panel per NEC code (which both electricians agreed to). The distance between the main and subpanel is going to be around 40ft.

Any suggestions or thoughts on this?

Comment: Main panel is the only place that grounds and neutrals can be connected/bonded.  Sub panels they must be separated.  Distance does not matter.  Is the sub panel inside the same building or a detached building?

Comment: If for a detached building, the ground for the sub panel might need to be separated from the main panel neutral bus.  Not sure but might what the electrician was referring to.

Comment: The 1st electrician may have misunderstood and thought you were make your main panel **into** a sub panel. That would explain the answer.

Comment: @crip659 it's not a detached building, the subpanel is going to be in the garage.

Comment: i could give benefit of doubt on the misunderstanding but i was pretty clear on my terms for the panels @DoxyLover

Answer (score 12):

The grounds and neutrals do not have to be separated in the main panel if it is, in fact, the main panel. Sometimes there's confusion if you have a main disconnect/breaker outside by the meter. In that case, that's the main panel and your breaker panel in the house would actually be a sub panel and neutrals and grounds would have to be separated. If your panel is fed directly from the meter and the only main disconnect is in the panel, then it's your main panel and neutrals and grounds don't need to be separated.

Comment: yes the panel is fed directly from the meter and its the only panel in the house currently where i can disconnect.